# .after() when i click this button .after the second not the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

I am using the `.after()` for adding some html to my page when I click a button. But when I add the html I want to skip the first place and go to the second.

```
$(this).after(newtemplate);
```

Basically I want `.after()` +1

Comment: Please read FAQ as [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question. Provide at least relevant HTML markup and better explain what you are looking for. Maybe what you mean is: `$(this).next().after(newtemplate);`

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is `append(newtemplate)`.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: I already Tried the append it didnt work.

   `$(this).next().after(newtemplate);`  

This worked for me.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Didn't have the time to double-check beforehand

Comment: No problem thanks for trying to help me. Its my first time posting a question to stackoverflow.com. and i like the fast response to my question.